# Can a dual SIM Android phone receive voice calls to both SIMs?

Tags: calls, dual-sim

Is it possible for a dual SIM phone to receive calls (not simultaneously of course) to both SIMs without any manual switching?

From what I have seen, Android 4.0 seems to support voice call for SIM #1 and video call (which seems to imply voice too) for SIM #2. That seems like you get 2G voice coverage for SIM #1 and 3G voice coverage for SIM #2. Is this true?

I guess this may vary depending on particular phone model, but what solution is Android dual-SIM industry mainstream currently?

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look at [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34632/how-does-gs3-dual-sim-adapter-work/34633#34633) question and my answer to have basic understanding on how the manufacturers use the terminologies.

These differences are hardware based and nothing to do with Android. Hence, if you had properly chosen your hardware:

- Yes, you can receive incoming calls in both SIMs without manual switching - even simultaneously! Yes, the other call will be treated as if you are receiving a call when you are on another on a single SIM phone. Depending on your settings and operator restrictions, you may have enabled call waiting and hence it will be displayed on your mobile screen. You can then hold one and switch to another.  This was tried in Samsung Galaxy Y Duos phone.

I am not sure about your other question about video call.

**Update:** In Samsung Galaxy Y Duos (a dual SIM phone) though both SIMs were active to receive calls and access Internet simultaneously, only one of them was allowed to use 3G network. If I opt for 3G network in SIM1 and opt for 3G on SIM2, a message says I can't use 3G on both and changes SIM1's network to 2G and retains SIM2's network to 3G as per my input.

Comment: Well, basically I was not asking about video call, just stating that video call automatically equals voice call ;-)

Comment: Do you know if Android can detect which type of dual sim a phone's capable of (i.e. prior to actually fitting the second sim & testing)?  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103765/how-to-tell-if-a-dual-sim-phone-is-dsds-or-dsfa

Comment: The part that says simultaneous incoming calls , simultaneous internet doesn't apply to every dual sim phone. @Jeffrey's answer explains about dual-standby.

Answer (score 4):

Android phone basically have two different dual SIM systems, AFAIK:

1. DSFA (Dual Sim Full Active): both SIMs can receive calls simultaneously, and you can switch between one call and the other
2. DSDS (Dual Sim Dual Standby): when one SIM is receiving a call, the other one is in standby. It will receive nor calls, nor SMS. It is like the second SIM is put in a phone turned off. As soon as the call ends, both will return to active state.

For more details, [this page from NGM](http://www.ngm.eu/dual-sim-tecnology/?lang=en) is pretty explicative.

Like DSFA and DSDS, also network coverage for different SIMs is all on the manufacturer's choice: I once had a cheap Dual SIM phone (not even a smartphone) which had a UMTS first slot and GSM second slot, but most smartphones today (all high-end ones for sure) offer LTE on both.

Android also allows you to select a favorite SIM for various action: you can always choose which number you want to call or send from, but if you have a plan good for messages and one made for voice calls, you can tell Android to send SMS from the first SIM and calls from the second, unless specified otherwise. So, you don't risk spending more than you should when forgetting to tell which SIM you want to use for a call, or to switch SIM.

Answer (score 1):

Dear Dual Sim active or simultaneously mean in any phone who support or have dual Sim Card phone and you received call at Sim one during your running Sim one call any one call at your second Sim who are its same phone where your call are running and you are able to pick 2nd Sim call bye holding 1st Sim call that was only Some China mobile phone before 4 year every coming phone and Samsung two model D780 and c3212 that all are Disconnected. Now no one Brand offering this function.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly Asus Z00AD is working with DSFA (Dual Sim Full Active): both SIMs can receive calls simultaneously, and you can switch between one call and the other