# How to tell if a dual sim phone is dsds or dsfa?

Tags: dual-sim, lg-g3

I recently learnt that there are different types of dual sim; i.e. that having slots for 2 sims doesn't mean they're both fully active at the same time.

Looking through the documentation included with my phone & attempting a few searches I haven't been able to find the answer; before requesting my office provide me with a work sim I'd like to know that my phone can handle it.

Is there a way to tell if your phone is dsds or dsfa (i.e. without using a second sim to test)?

Comment: Related info (though not an answer to the above) here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34632/how-does-gs3-dual-sim-adapter-work/34633#34633

Comment: Also related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41927/can-a-dual-sim-android-phone-receive-voice-calls-to-both-sims